# Vba to mark Check Box if specific cells contains specific imput

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

i need to create check box to be checked only if another specific cell contains specific input and unchecked if this input is not existing, noting that i tried below code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Ca()

Dim DestS As Worksheet
Set DestS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rest")

Dim DestSh As Range
Set DestSh = DestS.Range("B2")

If DestSh.Value = "Device" Then
DestS.CheckBoxes("Reset").Value = xlOn
Else
DestS.CheckBoxes("Reset").Value = xlOff
End If
End Sub
```

Also the check box i used is part of the forms toolbar not activeX and i changed the name of the check box to 'reset'

The error i got using debug is
method of checkbox of object _worksheet failed

Comment: I get that if the checkboxes are on the wrong sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next event code in the worksheet "rest" code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.value = "Device" Then
        CheckBoxes("Reset").value = True
    Else
        CheckBoxes("Reset").value = False
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

When you change the "B2" cell value in "Device", the check box will be checked. If you change its value in something else, the check box will be unchecked...

In order to copy the code in that sheet module, please activate sheet "rest" execute right click on the sheet name, choose `View Code` and copy the above code in the window which opens...

Comment: Yeah it worked fine, really i appericate your help and many thanks once a again.. but excuse me as i have an another inquiry.. if i need to recall the cell value B2 from another sheet what can i do

Comment: @Mostafa Nabil: I am afraid I do not understand what you mean... Do you mean to have a formula in "B2", which to be changed by modifications in another sheet? If yes, the change in such a cell value triggers `Worksheet_Calculate` event. What "recall the cell value" should mean, please? But it is late in my country and in some minutes I will close my laptop...

Comment: You can copy the same event in the code module of the sheet to monitor the range, but it is necessary to fully qualify the textbox object. I mean replacing of  `CheckBoxes("Reset")` wirh `Worksheets("rest").checkBoxes("Reset")`.

Comment: Thank you @faneduru it worked in another new sheet as there was a problem is the current sheet , thanks again